# "No such key" "The specified key does not exist" aws s3 bit bucket error while getting url from s3 bucket

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I just try to upload file to aws s3 bucket and try to get url from uploaded file but as soon as I get url I put it into browser and check but it give me error like
 NoSuchKey 
 The specified key does not exist. 
the code for getting url is-

```
  var expiryUrlRequest = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest();
expiryUrlRequest.BucketName = BUCKET_NAME;
expiryUrlRequest.Key = "uploads/xxx_" +xxx+ "/yyy_" + yyy+ "/" + FileName +   extention;      
expiryUrlRequest.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(10);
 url = client.GetPreSignedURL(expiryUrlRequest);
```

I store url in database and try to access file but give above error any help please.Thanks.

Using AWSSDK.S3 version v4.0.30319
using  AWSSDK.Core version v4.0.30319

Comment: I just tried it and it worked, is there any other information in the error?  Have you double checked the key?

Comment: is your bucket encrypted with a KMS key? check your IAM KMS encryption keys.

Comment: Issue is solved by adding one more / in key as /upload/xxx_12...... Thanks for your valuable advice.